# loading upcoming events by comparing their dates with the calendar date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nscalendar

I have found the below code online for comparing two dates (the date of the calendar and some another date) what I would like help with is modifying this code so that it compares the calendar date with the date of an event where date here is key for each event within NSArray (json file) .. Also how I could use this later with NSPredicate so that I can load only the events with components (difference between two dates in days) at least more than 1 day since Im going to have UIButton called future events when the user click on it, all the future events should be loaded .. I would really appreciate any help and code examples since Im very new to objective C and Xcode. Thanks.

```
@implementation HomeViewController {
    NSArray *_events;
}

- (BOOL)isSameDay:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
    //date = [_events objectAtIndex:date];

    unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents* comp1 = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
    NSDateComponents* comp2 = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:currDate];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:unitFlags
                                               fromDate:currDate
                                                 toDate:date
                                                options:0];

    NSLog(@"Days between dates: %@", components);

    return [comp1 day]   == [comp2 day] &&
    [comp1 month] == [comp2 month] &&
    [comp1 year]  == [comp2 year];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of days remaining for a date from now, you can use the method below:

```
-(long)daysRemaining:(NSDate*) date
{
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval dateDiff = [date timeIntervalSinceNow] - [now timeIntervalSinceNow];
    CGFloat numberOfDaysRemaining = (dateDiff/(60*60*24));
    return ceil(numberOfDaysRemaining);
}
```

So you can call to get the number of days remaining like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *dateToCompare = [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2014-02-08"];

long numberDays = [self daysRemaining:dateToCompare];
```

For this case, the result is **2** days remaining. Note that a negative result indicates that was passed **n** days.

To filter the array (2 days remaining events) making a copy of it:

```
NSArray* dates = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2014-02-08"],
    [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2014-02-05"],
    [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2014-02-10"],
    [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2014-02-08"], nil];

NSArray *filteredArray = [dates filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:
        ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
            long daysRemaining = [self daysRemaining:(NSDate*)evaluatedObject];
            return daysRemaining == 2; // if someMethod returns YES, the object is kept
        }
    ]];
```

To filter an NSMutableArray in place:

```
[mutableArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:
    ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        long daysRemaining = [self daysRemaining:(NSDate*)evaluatedObject];
        return daysRemaining == 2; // if someMethod returns YES, the object is kept
    }
]];
```

Comment: Thanks Felipe, so u are saying that I have to add all this code to my program so that the Future UIButton loads the future events ?? so no need to use NSCalendar or components:fromDate:toDate:options:0 function ?? and I didn't get why did u return the daysRemaining == 2 ?? in my case it should be 1 or greater i think !!..

Comment: The Future UIButton needs to load the data (if it is not already loaded) and then filter it using the predicate code. If you have a NSDate object or a string of the date, you don't need to use NSCalendar. To filter all future events, the correct is return (daysRemaining > 0). So if is a future event, the condition will return YES, and that event will be listed.

Comment: okay I got that but I have problem now, how could I modify this so it can include the date key for each event in my json file --> NSDate *dateToCompare = [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2014-02-08"];        and also what is the value of now in this line of code --> NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; and what does --> (id evaluatedObject) in ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) means ??

Comment: Maybe you have a json file that can be parsed into an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary element in array is an event, and each element in dictionary is the properties of the event, where one of these properties must be the date. Although this property is a string, you can parse into NSDate using [dateFormatter dateFromString: StringProperty] method within the code block of the Predicate.

Comment: ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) is a block of code that is called for each element in array, passing the element in evaluatedObject and receives a bool indicating if the element has or not to be included in the filtered array. So, responding NO for events with remaining days < or = 0, indicates that the predicate has to exclude this element, and YES to > 0, indicates that the predicate can maintain the element.

Comment: thanks Felipe for the clarification, basically I did it like that (below answer) but I got thread exception !!! I don't why .. do u see anything wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

```
  [displayedEvents addObjectsFromArray:[_events filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                          [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:
                           ^BOOL(Events * event, NSDictionary *bindings) {
                               [dateFormatter dateFromString: event.date];
                               long daysRemaining = [self daysRemaining: (NSDate*)event.date];
                               return daysRemaining > 1; // if someMethod returns YES, the object is kept
                           }
  ]]];
```